# auto deploy of tomcat server through tomcat plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

i want to auto deploy my tomcat server(which is not in eclipse) through my tomcat maven plugin...so i mentioned the goal as run....still is not running....how to mention the goal in tomcat plugin to start the tomcat server by default.

```
  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>tomcat-run</id>
                            <phase>package</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>tomcat7:deploy</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                        <server>myserver</server>
                        <path>/${project.artifactId}</path>
                        <username>username</username>
                        <password>password</password>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: with tomcat7:deploy you are not deploying a tomcat server, you deploying a war to tomcat. please refer to the plugin documentaion https://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html

Comment: yeah Hisham i changed that one to <goal>run-war-only</goal>  if i give a command like mvn install tomcat7:run  it is showing like this  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Tomcat
Apr 27, 2016 12:08:49 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Apr 27, 2016 12:08:57 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"] but 
the url http://localhost:8080/manager/text is not working....it is showing 404 error...any solution for this???